# Move a textbox towards left and right directions on click of left and right buttons c# uwp

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to move a textbox towards left if i click on moveleft button and towards right side if i click moveright button

I tried with translate transform but my textbox is not moving accordingly.

Small sample is highly appreciated

Comment: What have you tried with translate transform? Its there for a reason, and that is because it works, maybe you did it wrong. Try providing some code samples from your own code, so others can help fix YOUR problem and not just give you the answer as a fixed solution.

Comment: You need to put the `TranslateTransform` in `RenderTransform`.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you refer to [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.translatetransform?view=winrt-22621), which describes how to use `TranslateTransform`.

The following is a sample that I wrote for your reference, so as to help you find out problems.

### Page.xmal

```
<Grid>

    <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
        <TextBox x:Name="testTxT" Text="A sample Text">
            <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="txtTranslateTransform"/>
            </TextBox.RenderTransform>
        </TextBox>
    </Canvas>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="btnToLeft" Content="Left" Width="100" Click="btnToLeft_Click"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="btntoRight" Content="Right" Width="100" Click="btntoRight_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

### Page.xmal.cs

```
    private void btnToLeft_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtTranslateTransform.X = txtTranslateTransform.X - 15;
    }

    private void btntoRight_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtTranslateTransform.X= txtTranslateTransform.X + 15;
    }
```